# is it possible dynamically enable/disable a directive in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8, directive

I'm using **ngbDropdownMenu** directive, I want to be able to disable that directive under some special conditions like bellow:

```
  <div [ngbDropdownMenu]="Some Condition Here"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't , `ngbDropdownMenu` is not designed to accept a condition, However you can do  like this:

```
<ng-container  *ngIf="<someCondition> else someTemplate">
   <div [ngbDropdownMenu]> </div>
  ... 
</ng-container>

<ng-template #someTemplate>
    <div>something else to show if condition is not met</div>
</ng-template>
```